# What are some great exercises for adult recorder players?

Tags: practice, recorder

I have several adults who want to relearn recorder playing and play Renaissance music, especially dance pieces.  They want exercises to familiarize the fingerings and reading.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​What type of recorder are you using? There are many different types of recorders, and the fingerings differ for them.

Answer (score 1):

For Renaissance dances, I'd expect the main time drain for "relearning recorder playing" to be articulation.  For a pleasant combination with other instruments, both regarding intonatory blend-in while maintaining discernible voice leading, Renaissance recorder play seems to stand and fall with the player's mastery of leggiero.